# C error: expected `=', `,', `;', `asm' or `__attribute__' before

Tags: c, cygwin, powerpc

I am trying to compile matlab generated code  for 565 powerPC under cygwin.
When I execute the following compile  command:

```
@powerpc-eabi-gcc -gdwarf-2 -c -mno-sdata -DMODEL=testMacs -DRT -DNUMST=2 
-DTID01EQ=1 -DNCSTATES=0 -DRT_STATIC -DMT=0 -I. 
-IC:/Programs/MATLAB/R2007b/simulink/include 
-IC:/Programs/MATLAB/R2007b/extern/include -IC:/cygwin/gnu/powerpc/extern
2/includes 
-IC:/Programs/MATLAB/R2007b/rtw/c/src 
-IC:/Programs/MATLAB/R2007b/rtw/c/libsrc 
-IC:/cygwin/powerpc-eabi/powerpc-eabi/sys-include 
-IC:/macs_565_R14/Driver 
-IC:/cygwin/ecos/include 
-mcpu=505 -O1 -o ./obj/testMacs.o testMacs.c
```

I Get the following error:

```
In file included from testMacs.h:16:0,
                 from testMacs.c:11:
C:/cygwin/powerpc-eabi/powerpc-eabi/sys-include/math.h:12:1: error: expected `=', `,', `;', `asm' or `__attribute__' before `union'
C:/cygwin/powerpc-eabi/powerpc-eabi/sys-include/math.h:398:17: error: expected `=', `,', `;', `asm' or `__attribute__' before `const'
In file included from rtwtypes.h:12:0,
                 from testMacs.h:17,
                 from testMacs.c:11:
C:/Programs/MATLAB/R2007b/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:83:1: error: expected `=', `,', `;', `asm' or `__attribute__' before `typedef'
```

The math.h rtwtypes.h are standard unchanged header files.

Does anyone know what I do wrong or am I missing a compiler option.

Code snippeds:
testMacs.h:

```
/*
 * testMacs.h
 *
 * Real-Time Workshop code generation for Simulink model "testMacs.mdl".
 *
 * Model Version              : 1.6
 * Real-Time Workshop version : 7.0.1  (R2007b+)  21-Apr-2008
 * C source code generated on : Mon Apr 23 06:48:14 2012
 */
#ifndef RTW_HEADER_testMacs_h_
#define RTW_HEADER_testMacs_h_
#ifndef testMacs_COMMON_INCLUDES_
# define testMacs_COMMON_INCLUDES_
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>            /* line 16*/
#include "rtwtypes.h"        /* line 17*/
#include "simstruc.h"
#include "fixedpoint.h"
#include "rt_logging.h"
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#endif
```

math.h:

```
/* math.h -- Definitions for the math floating point package.  */

#ifndef  _MATH_H_
#define  _MATH_H_

#include <sys/reent.h>
#include <machine/ieeefp.h>
#include "_ansi.h"

_BEGIN_STD_C

union __dmath             /* line 12*/
{
  __ULong i[2];
  double d;
};
```

...
...

```
/* Global control over fdlibm error handling.  */

enum __fdlibm_version
{
  __fdlibm_ieee = -1,
  __fdlibm_svid,
  __fdlibm_xopen,
  __fdlibm_posix
};

    #define _LIB_VERSION_TYPE enum __fdlibm_version
    #define _LIB_VERSION __fdlib_version

    extern __IMPORT _CONST _LIB_VERSION_TYPE _LIB_VERSION;      /*line 398*/

    #define _IEEE_  __fdlibm_ieee
    #define _SVID_  __fdlibm_svid
    #define _XOPEN_ __fdlibm_xopen
    #define _POSIX_ __fdlibm_posix
```

rtwtypes.h:

```
/*
 * File: rtwtypes.h
 *
 * Definitions required by Real-Time Workshop generated code.
 *
 * Real-Time Workshop version: 7.0.1
 * Generated on: 2012-04-23 06:48:15
 */

#ifndef __RTWTYPES_H__
#define __RTWTYPES_H__
#include "tmwtypes.h"             /* line 12*/

/* This ID is used to detect inclusion of an incompatible rtwtypes.h */
#define RTWTYPES_ID_C08S16I32L32N32F1
#include "simstruc_types.h"
#ifndef POINTER_T
# define POINTER_T
```

tmwtypes.h:

```
/*
 *      The following define is used to emulate when all integer types are
 *      32-bits.  This is the case for TI C30/C40 DSPs which are RTW targets.
 */
#ifdef DSP32
# define INT8_T    int
# define UINT8_T   unsigned int
# define INT16_T   int
# define UINT16_T  unsigned int
#endif
                                      /* line 83*/
/*
 * The uchar_T, ushort_T and ulong_T types are needed for compilers which do 
 * not allow defines to be specified, at the command line, with spaces in them.
 */

typedef unsigned char  uchar_T;
typedef unsigned short ushort_T;
typedef unsigned long  ulong_T;
```

Comment: And what is `testMacs.c`?  The error suggests you have something before the `#include`s which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Are you sure that's line 83 of `C:/Programs/MATLAB/R2007b/extern/include/tmwtypes.h` - i.e., that  you're looking in the right directory? Throwing an error on a blank line doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `_BEGIN_STD_C` is not being defined (as well as maybe some other macros) when `math.h` is being processed.  However, that (at least `_BEGIN_STD_C`) should have been taken care of by `_ansi.h`.

Try compiling with the `-M` option to make sure the right headers are being included and/or compiling with `-E` so you can look at the preprocessor output.  One of these should point to the problem.

Comment: This helped me allot I could see that the _asni.h file was included from many different sources.